# Not getting provider_job_id inside active jobs for delayed_job adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, delayed-job, rails-activejob

I'm trying to get the `provider_job_id` inside the ActiveJob, but it is getting as nil

Using `delayed_job` as queue adapter

```
class Application < Rails::Application
  config.active_job.queue_adapter = :delayed_job
end
```

On debug I found that getting provider_job_id inside `after_enqueue` callback, but it is nil inside `before_perform` callback.

```
class MyJob < ApplicationJob
  def perform(email)
    # get provider_job_id for another purpose
    jid = self.provider_job_id # this is nil
  end
end
```

Job is queued as

```
job = MyJob.set(wait: 30.minutes).perform_later('dummy@example.com')
jid = job.provider_job_id # getting provider_job_id here
```

In my case, I'm calling job to perform immediately after it is enqueued on specific case using delayed job as below

```
Delayed::Job.find(jid).invoke_job
```

Anyone has idea about why provider_job_id is nil inside job class?

Also, **how can we trigger Active Job to invoke immediately once it is enqueued like delayed job ?**

I can see fix is applied for sidekiq adapter [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/25961/files#diff-e1ee600ca5fd100da20810ef5acbab89546064fc323c7b1e6bdb6ed5e681a9d3R40)
but for delayed job it is not there [here](https://github.com/kelhusseiny/rails/blob/80e825915c7ff638f4b668a7cca1be46903cb433/activejob/lib/active_job/queue_adapters/delayed_job_adapter.rb#L36)

Comment: This appears to work https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/1118. Cannot vouche for its accuracy.